# Using E4X to find distinct values in an XML list

Tags: javascript, e4x

Consider this XML snippet:

```
 <book id="5" />
 <book id="15" />
 <book id="5" />
 <book id="25" />
 <book id="35" />
 <book id="5" />
```

How can I compose an E4X statement/query to get a list of the unique values in the `id` attribute? I'm using E4X in a JavaScript non-browser context.

```
5
15
25
35
```

Is there a `distinct()` or `groupby()` method of any kind that would help? If not, how could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique or groupby method. However, E4X allow you to quickly create an XMLList of the values non-unique values.

```
var xmlSnippet = <stuff><book id="5"/>
                        <book id="15"/>
                        <book id="5"/>
                        <book id="25"/>
                        <book id="35"/>
                        <book id="5"/>
                  </stuff>;
var attributes = xmlSnippet['book'].attribute("id");
```

To make it unique, you can then take the XMLList, iterate through it, and store each element as the key value in an object.

```
var uniqueAttributes = new Object ();

for each (var a in attributes)
{
    uniqueAttributes[a] = null;
}
```

To access these values, iterate through them using a for in loop (not a for each in)

```
for (var u in uniqueAttributes)
{
// do something with u
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This presumes the attribute values in question do not contain a pipe, "|", character.  If so then change the pipe character at the very bottom to something else not in the values.  The variables are statically typed for JIT execution.  Hope this does what you need.

```
var idvalues = function (x) { //x = node name
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName(x),
        b,
        c = [],
        d,
        e;
    for (b = a.length - 1; b > -1; b -= 1) { // gather all the id values into an array
        c.push(a[b].getAttribute("id"));
    }
    for (b = c.length - 1; b > -1; b -= 1) {
        if (c[b] !== "") {
            for (d = b - 1; d > -1; d -=1) {
                if (c[b] === c[d]) {
                    c[d] = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    e = c.join("|");
    c = e.split("|");
    return c;
};
```